# Sublime Text 3: Build Plots (Python) inline (within build window)

Tags: python, matplotlib, build, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 and building my Python scripts within Sublime (CTRL + B).

Since I am using `matplotlib.pyplot` a lot, I want the created plots to show up **within** the build window and NOT in an popup-window.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: The build window is a text window like a console. What makes you think that it can show graphics? Is there any hint or evidence for that?

Comment: An editor called 'spyder' (comes with Anaconda) can do something like this. But I just recognized, that the file is executed in an IPython-Console. I'll work around a little bit. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Apparently you can use a sublime package called [Hermes](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Hermes) to connect to a jupyter server. Although I haven't been able to get it to establish the connection.